# Will Hibernates Session.get() hit the database both times or only one time?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

When we are using Hibernate's Session.get() two times.

Example :-

```
session.get();
session.get();
```

Comment: When you put a question please put the explained queistion with the your tried code.

Answer (score 0):

It depends..

**1)** If a second level cache is turned on for a particular entity and it has been retrieved previously, there will be no hit to the database.

**2)** If both `get()` ARE NOT within the same persistence context (usually meaning within the same transaction), then both times there will be a hit to the database.

**3)** If both ARE within the same persistence context, then the first `get()` will hit the database and the second one will only query the persistence context without the need of querying the database.